# Why can't nginx access puma socket on CentOS 7?

Tags: permissions, ruby, nginx, rails, centos-7

So I have a Ruby on Rails app in `/var/www/` owned by `nginx` with `755` permissions. Said app is intended to be deployed via puma.

Like so:

```
rvmsudo -u nginx bundle exec puma -e production -d -b unix:///var/www/my_app/tmp/sockets/my_app.socket
```

The permissions for the socket are:

```
srwxrwxrwx. 1 nginx nginx 0 Nov  6 09:43 tmp/sockets/my_app.sock
```

The process is, of course, owned by nginx:

```
nginx     7335  0.0  8.8 536744 90388 ?        Sl   09:43   0:00 puma 2.9.2 (unix:///var/www/my_app/tmp/sockets/my_app.sock)
```

My `nginx` configuration configuration is as follows:

```
upstream my_app {
  server unix:///var/www/my_app/tmp/sockets/my_app.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  root /var/www/my_app/public;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://my_app;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

All of this and my application is still denied permissions.

```
connect() to unix:///var/www/my_app/tmp/sockets/my_app.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream,
```

I have tried all of this as the root user, also. But it still does not work.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Same for me. Did you found a solution?

Comment: Yes I did! See answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hallelujah! This all turned out to be an SELinux policy issue specifically pertaining to nginx. After hours of digging, I discovered such denials by running:

```
sudo grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

The messages looked like so:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1415283617.227:1386): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=1683 comm="nginx" name="my_app.sock" dev="tmpfs" ino=20657 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_run_t:s0 tclass=sock_file
```

In order to fix this, I found a wonderful article by [Axilleas](http://axilleas.me/en/blog/2013/selinux-policy-for-nginx-and-gitlab-unix-socket-in-fedora-19/).

To create the policy containing the necessary permissions, I had to install `audit2allow` and run:

```
grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M nginx
```

Once done, I finalized the policy with:

```
semodule -i nginx.pp
```

Unfortunately, I had to run this process twice before being able to access my application because further policies were needed. Nonetheless, here was the solution.

Also, there is another nice article by [Sergiy Krylkov](http://sergiy.kyrylkov.name/2012/02/26/phusion-passenger-with-apache-on-rhel-6-centos-6-sl-6-with-selinux/).

Moral of the story: learn SELinux.

Comment: Thank You very much!!! I've spend tens of hours digging entire internet. It works now!

Comment: No problem! Glad my experience could help someone else.